# Am I able to install Skyrim on a second computer, provided I am using my same Steam account?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I would like to install Skyrim also on my desktop. I was wondering if Steam will let me install Skyrim on another PC also? If not, I don't want to go through setting it up and downloading it, all 7 or so GB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can install steam games on as many computers as you want.

The catch, is that you may only be connected to steam from one computer at a time. For a game like Skyrim, however, running in Steam's Offline mode isn't much of an issue.

Comment: Yep, I have it on my laptop on desktop, it's just like Raven Dreamer says.

Comment: @gameaddict happy to be of service!